# Raster Values into Gridded Polygons with Same Cell Size using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, vectorization

I have data in the form of a raster with 1 km x 1 km cells. I need to transfer it into a vector polygon grid layer (USNG) which also has 1 km x km cells, but has divergence around UTM zones and does not match up with the raster.

How does one accurately transform raster to polygon data for the same cell size, but different cell locations?

I am using ArcMap.

Comment: What GIS software are you using to try and do this?  What have you tried?

Comment: I am currently working in ArcMap, but will be switching over to ArcGIS Pro. I have tried converting Raster to Point and performing a spatial join to the USNG, and also performing a zonal statistics as table. These methods work, but I believe they are losing accuracy

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.